# Independence of random variable?

Tags: probability-distributions, independence

I'm having trouble with this statement: 
If X and Y are independent and Y and Z are independent does this mean that X and Z are independent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't imply that $X$ and $Z$ are independent. They might be independent, but they need not be independent. As an extreme example let $X$ and $Y$ be independent, and let let $Z=X$.

One should probably give an explicit example. A fair dime and a fair quarter are tossed. Let $X=1$ if we get a head on the dime, and let $X=0$ otherwise. Let $Y=1$ if we get a head on the quarter, and $0$ otherwise. Let $Z=X$. It is clear (and easy to show) that $X$ and $Z$ are not independent.  But in a standard model of coin tossing, $X$ and $Y$ are independent and, for the same reason, $Y$ and $Z$ are independent.